# I bought multigrain bread from the store last week (panera brand) and it has white smelly patch

Tags: bread

[image]I bought multigrain bread from the store last week (panera brand) and it has white smelly patch.And saw some really big white patches. It smells bad as well. Manufacturing company said its white mold. But they looked different than mold. Any thought would be appreciated?

Comment: if the company said it's mold and you're not gonna eat it anyway why not just return it to the store? What do you need help with?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I had actually consumed 2 pieces before I saw it. I am 5 months pregnant and I am trying to identify what I ate. Requesting for any second opinion if that substance could be anything else because manufacturing company stop responding to me now when i asked for lab report.

Comment: Honestly, if you ate 2 pieces you're probably going to be fine (disclaimer: I'm not a doctor). Since you already ate, there's not much to do now, just don't eat any more of it. It looks like mold to me.

Comment: Thank You for your opinion. Little bit consumption of white mold isn't very bad, is what I have read so far. So as long as it is not any chemical contamination, I am trying to not panic but I am consulting with my doctor tomorrow. It didnt make me sick or anything either. SO I am hoping for everything to be ok. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

Mold comes in many different colors and textures. I have seen white, green, black and even orange hues on bread, long haired ones and others that look like dust. The only other possible explanation for white spots may be flour from dusting, but we can safely exclude that here, this bread doesn’t show a floury crust.

In short, if it grows on your bread and smells weird, you may safely assume it’s a kind of mold. Bread is a good, nutritious base for mold spores, especially if it’s slightly damp in the bag. Further id is not required, mold on bread should not be eaten. Discard the bread, wipe the counter or board, move on.